# How do you set S3_KEY and S3_SECRET .env vars in rails / AWS / heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, environment-variables

I'm doing [this heroku tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ios-photo-sharing-geo-location-service#add-image-upload-columns).

In the tutorial it mentions I need to set environment variables for S3_KEY, S3_SECRET, and S3_BUCKET.

I've created a S3 Bucket on AWS (Amazon Web Services), and I've used the unique name of the Bucket as my .env (I've created a .env file in my Rails project, and added it to .gitignore) S3_BUCKET variable.

However, in the tutorial I need to set **S3_KEY and S3_SECRET.**

**Where do I find these variables?** I can't seem to find them anywhere on AWS/S3. Am I suppose to generate these vars or what's the deal with these?

Second question: I will then have a model Photo that looks like this...

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file   :image,
                        :styles => { thumbnail: "100x100#" },
                        :storage => :s3,
                        :s3_credentials => {    :access_key_id  => ENV['S3_KEY'],
                                                :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET'],
                                                :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET'] }
end
```

**Will this now work in all my environments, including prod on heroku,** or do I need to do anything special with heroku?

Answer (score 2):

What you did here below is establish what these variables were for.

```
:s3_credentials => {    :access_key_id  => ENV['S3_KEY'],
                                                :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET'],
                                                :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET'] }
```

Now you need to set the actual values of the variables in production.

To create a new key and secret key, go to your AWS management console, and click your name in the top right. Next click security credentials and generate a new access key pair. Use these below.

To set your AWS variables for heroku, do this from the command line:

```
$ heroku config:set S3_KEY=xxxxxxxxxx S3_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Obviously replace the x's with your actual keys. Check here if you want more info about Config variables: [Heroku Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

One final note that you're probably aware of, but is worth mentioning anyways. Make sure you never push an actual AWS key to Github (even a private repo). There are people out scraping Github specifically for AWS keys, and it could cost you a lot of money if they find them.

Regarding your second questions, I would use local storage for test/dev environments. Do something like this:

```
 if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?
    :storage = :file
 else
    :storage = :s3
 end
```

Comment: Thanks settheline,

Once I get the S3 keys to set heroku's config vars, do I also use these same keys to set those same vars in my .env?

Also, can you elaborate on what I would want for the :storage = **:file** file part.

Comment: It looks like you will use the same keys in your .env, yes. I recommended using local file storage in development to avoid any conflicts in your buckets. You can use the .env as the tutorial says, but it looks like you will need to be using Foreman.

Comment: I had to use storage :fog instead of :s3. I'm using the fog gem